# Ranged for loop with literal list?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, initializer-list

In C++11, is it possible to write the following

```
int ns[] = { 1, 5, 6, 2, 9 };
for (int n : ns) {
   ...
}
```

as something like this

```
for (int n : { 1, 5, 6, 2, 9 }) { // VC++11 rejects this form
   ...
}
```

Comment: VS13 accepts this, see it [here](http://rextester.com/DTEHL66513)

Comment: @JohnOdom: That looks like Java. Are you sure you're using the right language?

Comment: Yeah sorry, was thinking Java, xD

Comment: Sometimes it helps to try things in one of the many [online C++ compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***tl;dr:** Upgrade your compiler for great success.*

---

**Yeah, it's valid.**

The definition of ranged-for in `[C++11: 6.5.4/1]` gives us two variants of syntax for this construct. One takes an *expression* on the right-hand-side of the `:`, and the other takes a *braced-init-list*.

Your *braced-init-list* deduces (through `auto`) to a `std::initializer_list`, which is handy because these things may be iterated over.

> *[..]* for a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> `for (` *for-range-declaration* `:` *braced-init-list* `) statement`
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *braced-init-list*. In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>    auto && __range = range-init;
>    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>               __end = end-expr;
>         __begin != __end;
>         ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> *[..]*

So, you are basically saying:

```
auto ns = { 1, 5, 6, 2, 9 };
for (int n : ns) {
   // ...
}
```

<sup>(I haven't bothered with the universal reference here.)</sup>

which in turn is more-or-less equivalent to:

```
std::initializer_list<int> ns = { 1, 5, 6, 2, 9 };
for (int n : ns) {
   // ...
}
```

Now, [GCC 4.8 supports this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09bbc7b88337e4a8) but, since "Visual Studio 11" is in fact Visual Studio 2012, you'll need to upgrade in order to catch up: **[initialiser lists were not supported *at all* until Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)**.

Comment: Since when do you quote a compiler in the wild as the authoritative source? I mean, I **know** it's correct, but I'm expecting a standards quote/link to existing answer from you :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use this construction with an initializer list. Simply it seems the MS VC++ you are using does not support it.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int main() 
{
    for (int n : { 1, 5, 6, 2, 9 }) std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You have to include header `<initializer_list>` because the initializer list in the for statement is converted to `std::initializer_list<int>`